# Use ngRoute in html view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-routing

i want to use the NgRoute to get the params from the url sent this for change the Location from the static map here is my code but i got no ide how to implement $route in the HTML view

That i want to do is to get the LAT AND LNG Sent via param from URL and change it into ng-src, just want to learn how to get the params 
Thanks

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',  ['ngRoute'], function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});



var controller = function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.route = $routeParams;

  //Technically here it gets the URL PARAMS 
  $scope.e = {
    location:"Albany, NY",
    locationAbout:"Try an address, a city, a place, or even latitude and longitude.",
    API:"",
    APIAbout:"You don't always need an API Key for Static Maps, but it's easy to acquire one. Without a key you might receive an error image instead of a map. Follow the link to the API Console.",
    zoom:13,
    minZoom:0,
    maxZoom:22,
    scaleAbout:"Scale will double the stated height and width. This is good for when you need a width or height larger than 640px.",
    width:600,
    height:300,
    maxSize:640,
    sizeAbout:"Max is 640px or 1280px when scale 2x.",
    markerColor: "red",
    mapType: "roadmap",
    format:"png",
    markerSize:"mid",
    gimmeAbout:"Treat this like a regular image. Pop it into an img tag or use as a background-image."    
  };
  $scope.colors =
    [
    "black",
    "brown",
    "green",
    "purple",
    "yellow",
    "blue",
    "gray",
    "orange",
    "red",
    "white"
  ];
  $scope.markerSizes =
    [
    { "value": "tiny", "text": "small" },
    { "value": "small", "text": "medium" },
    { "value": "mid", "text": "large" }
  ];
  $scope.mapTypes =
    [
    "roadmap",
    "terrain",
    "satellite",
    "hybrid"
  ];
  $scope.formats =
    [
    "png",
    "png32",
    "gif",
    "jpg",
    "jpg-baseline"
  ];

};


$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
  placement : 'right',
  trigger:'hover'
});




/*
 AngularJS v1.2.15
 (c) 2010-2014 Google, Inc. http://angularjs.org
 License: MIT
*/
(function(n,e,A){'use strict';function x(s,g,k){return{restrict:"ECA",terminal:!0,priority:400,transclude:"element",link:function(a,c,b,f,w){function y(){p&&(p.remove(),p=null);h&&(h.$destroy(),h=null);l&&(k.leave(l,function(){p=null}),p=l,l=null)}function v(){var b=s.current&&s.current.locals;if(e.isDefined(b&&b.$template)){var b=a.$new(),d=s.current;l=w(b,function(d){k.enter(d,null,l||c,function(){!e.isDefined(t)||t&&!a.$eval(t)||g()});y()});h=d.scope=b;h.$emit("$viewContentLoaded");h.$eval(u)}else y()}
var h,l,p,t=b.autoscroll,u=b.onload||"";a.$on("$routeChangeSuccess",v);v()}}}function z(e,g,k){return{restrict:"ECA",priority:-400,link:function(a,c){var b=k.current,f=b.locals;c.html(f.$template);var w=e(c.contents());b.controller&&(f.$scope=a,f=g(b.controller,f),b.controllerAs&&(a[b.controllerAs]=f),c.data("$ngControllerController",f),c.children().data("$ngControllerController",f));w(a)}}}n=e.module("ngRoute",["ng"]).provider("$route",function(){function s(a,c){return e.extend(new (e.extend(function(){},
{prototype:a})),c)}function g(a,e){var b=e.caseInsensitiveMatch,f={originalPath:a,regexp:a},k=f.keys=[];a=a.replace(/([().])/g,"\\$1").replace(/(\/)?:(\w+)([\?\*])?/g,function(a,e,b,c){a="?"===c?c:null;c="*"===c?c:null;k.push({name:b,optional:!!a});e=e||"";return""+(a?"":e)+"(?:"+(a?e:"")+(c&&"(.+?)"||"([^/]+)")+(a||"")+")"+(a||"")}).replace(/([\/$\*])/g,"\\$1");f.regexp=RegExp("^"+a+"$",b?"i":"");return f}var k={};this.when=function(a,c){k[a]=e.extend({reloadOnSearch:!0},c,a&&g(a,c));if(a){var b=
"/"==a[a.length-1]?a.substr(0,a.length-1):a+"/";k[b]=e.extend({redirectTo:a},g(b,c))}return this};this.otherwise=function(a){this.when(null,a);return this};this.$get=["$rootScope","$location","$routeParams","$q","$injector","$http","$templateCache","$sce",function(a,c,b,f,g,n,v,h){function l(){var d=p(),m=r.current;if(d&&m&&d.$$route===m.$$route&&e.equals(d.pathParams,m.pathParams)&&!d.reloadOnSearch&&!u)m.params=d.params,e.copy(m.params,b),a.$broadcast("$routeUpdate",m);else if(d||m)u=!1,a.$broadcast("$routeChangeStart",
d,m),(r.current=d)&&d.redirectTo&&(e.isString(d.redirectTo)?c.path(t(d.redirectTo,d.params)).search(d.params).replace():c.url(d.redirectTo(d.pathParams,c.path(),c.search())).replace()),f.when(d).then(function(){if(d){var a=e.extend({},d.resolve),c,b;e.forEach(a,function(d,c){a[c]=e.isString(d)?g.get(d):g.invoke(d)});e.isDefined(c=d.template)?e.isFunction(c)&&(c=c(d.params)):e.isDefined(b=d.templateUrl)&&(e.isFunction(b)&&(b=b(d.params)),b=h.getTrustedResourceUrl(b),e.isDefined(b)&&(d.loadedTemplateUrl=
b,c=n.get(b,{cache:v}).then(function(a){return a.data})));e.isDefined(c)&&(a.$template=c);return f.all(a)}}).then(function(c){d==r.current&&(d&&(d.locals=c,e.copy(d.params,b)),a.$broadcast("$routeChangeSuccess",d,m))},function(c){d==r.current&&a.$broadcast("$routeChangeError",d,m,c)})}function p(){var a,b;e.forEach(k,function(f,k){var q;if(q=!b){var g=c.path();q=f.keys;var l={};if(f.regexp)if(g=f.regexp.exec(g)){for(var h=1,p=g.length;h<p;++h){var n=q[h-1],r="string"==typeof g[h]?decodeURIComponent(g[h]):
g[h];n&&r&&(l[n.name]=r)}q=l}else q=null;else q=null;q=a=q}q&&(b=s(f,{params:e.extend({},c.search(),a),pathParams:a}),b.$$route=f)});return b||k[null]&&s(k[null],{params:{},pathParams:{}})}function t(a,c){var b=[];e.forEach((a||"").split(":"),function(a,d){if(0===d)b.push(a);else{var e=a.match(/(\w+)(.*)/),f=e[1];b.push(c[f]);b.push(e[2]||"");delete c[f]}});return b.join("")}var u=!1,r={routes:k,reload:function(){u=!0;a.$evalAsync(l)}};a.$on("$locationChangeSuccess",l);return r}]});n.provider("$routeParams",
function(){this.$get=function(){return{}}});n.directive("ngView",x);n.directive("ngView",z);x.$inject=["$route","$anchorScroll","$animate"];z.$inject=["$compile","$controller","$route"]})(window,window.angular);
//# sourceMappingURL=angular-route.min.js.map
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">

 <title>Sistema de Alarmas Ever-Track</title>

 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Oxygen+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://staticmapmaker.com/css/main.css'>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

 <body ng-app="myApp">

  
  
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="toggle">
  <header class="col col-right">
   <h1><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Ever-Track GPS System    </h1>
   <a href="#" class="link">Sistema de rastreo de Alarmas</a>
  </header>

  <div class="main" ng-controller="controller">
   <div class="col-left col">
    <label for="toggle" class="label-toggle">
     <span class="close-it"><span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></span></span>
     <span class="open-it"><span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></span></span>
    </label>

    <div class="controls">

     <div class="container" >

      <form>
       <fieldset ng-show="false">

        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="location" class="cushion">Location [[route]] <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-content="[[e.locationAbout]]"></i></label>
         <div class="form-control" ><input type="text" ng-model="e.location" id="location"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="api" class="cushion">
          <a href="https://code.google.com/apis/console/" target="_blank">API Key</a>
          <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-content="[[e.APIAbout]]"></i></label>
          <div class="form-control"><input type="text" ng-model="e.API" id="api" placeholder="API Key"></div>
         </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="zoom">Zoom</label>
          <div class="form-control"><input type="range" name="input" ng-model="e.zoom" min="[[e.minZoom]]" max="[[e.maxZoom]]" id="zoom"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="scale">Scale (2x) <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-content="[[e.scaleAbout]]"></i>
          </label>
          <div class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="scale" ng-true-value="2" ng-false-value="1" id="scale" ng-init="scale='false'"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="width" class="cushion">Ancho <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-content="[[e.sizeAbout]]"></i></label>
          <div class="form-control"><input type="number" ng-model="e.width" min="0" max="[[e.maxSize]]" id="width"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="height" class="cushion">Alto <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-content="[[e.sizeAbout]]"></i>
          </label>
          <div class="form-control"><input type="number" ng-model="e.height" min="0" max="[[e.maxSize]]" id="height"></div>
         </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset ng-show="false">
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="showMarker">Map Marker</label>
          <div class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="showMarker" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" id="showMarker"></div>
         </div>
         <ng-switch on="showMarker">
         <ng-switch ng-switch-when="true">
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="markerColor"> Marker Color</label>
          <div class="form-control"><select ng-model="e.markerColor"
           ng-options="color for color in colors" id="markerColor">
          </select></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="markerSize"> Marker Size</label>
          <div class="form-control"><select ng-model="e.markerSize"
           ng-options="markerSize.value as markerSize.text for markerSize in markerSizes" id="markerSize">
          </select></div>
         </div>
        </ng-switch>
       </ng-switch>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mapType"> Tipo de Mapa</label>
        <div class="form-control"><select ng-model="e.mapType"
         ng-options="mapType for mapType in mapTypes" id="mapType">
        </select></div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="format"> Formato imagen</label>
        <div class="form-control"><select ng-model="e.format"
         ng-options="format for format in formats" id="format">
        </select></div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="visual"> Efecto Virtual</label>
        <div class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="visual" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-init="visual='true'" id="visual"></div>
       </div>
      </fieldset>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-right col">
   <div class="static">

    <img ng-src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=[[e.location.split(' ').join('+')]]&zoom=[[e.zoom]]&scale=[[scale]]&size=[[e.width]]x[[e.height]]&maptype=[[e.mapType]]&sensor=false[[ e.API !== '' && '&key='+e.API || '' ]]&format=[[e.format]]&visual_refresh=[[visual]][[ showMarker == 'true' && '&markers=size:'+e.markerSize+'%7Ccolor:'+e.markerColor+'%7C'+e.location.split(' ').join('+') || '' ]]" alt="Google Map of [[e.location]]" class="static-map" id="map">

   </div>
   <div class="tabs">


   </div>

  </div>
 </div>

</body>

<script src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.15/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});

var controller = function($scope) {
  $scope.e = {
    location:"Albany, NY",
    locationAbout:"Try an address, a city, a place, or even latitude and longitude.",
    API:"",
    APIAbout:"You don't always need an API Key for Static Maps, but it's easy to acquire one. Without a key you might receive an error image instead of a map. Follow the link to the API Console.",
    zoom:13,
    minZoom:0,
    maxZoom:22,
    scaleAbout:"Scale will double the stated height and width. This is good for when you need a width or height larger than 640px.",
    width:600,
    height:300,
    maxSize:640,
    sizeAbout:"Max is 640px or 1280px when scale 2x.",
    markerColor: "red",
    mapType: "roadmap",
    format:"png",
    markerSize:"mid",
    gimmeAbout:"Treat this like a regular image. Pop it into an img tag or use as a background-image."
  };
  $scope.colors =
    [
    "black",
    "brown",
    "green",
    "purple",
    "yellow",
    "blue",
    "gray",
    "orange",
    "red",
    "white"
  ];
  $scope.markerSizes =
    [
    { "value": "tiny", "text": "small" },
    { "value": "small", "text": "medium" },
    { "value": "mid", "text": "large" }
  ];
  $scope.mapTypes =
    [
    "roadmap",
    "terrain",
    "satellite",
    "hybrid"
  ];
  $scope.formats =
    [
    "png",
    "png32",
    "gif",
    "jpg",
    "jpg-baseline"
  ];

};


$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
  placement : 'right',
  trigger:'hover'
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

 <meta charset="UTF-8">

 <title>Sistema de Alarmas Ever-Track</title>

 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Oxygen+Mono' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://staticmapmaker.com/css/main.css'>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" type="text/css" />

</head>

<body>

 <body ng-app="myApp">
 
  <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" id="toggle">
  <header class="col col-right">
   <h1><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Ever-Track GPS System    </h1>
   <a href="#" class="link">Sistema de rastreo de Alarmas</a>
  </header>

  <div class="main" ng-controller="controller">
   <div class="col-left col">
    <label for="toggle" class="label-toggle">
     <span class="close-it"><span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></span></span>
     <span class="open-it"><span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></span></span>
    </label>

    <div class="controls">

     <div class="container" >

      <form>
       <fieldset ng-show="false">

        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="location" class="cushion">Location <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-content="[[e.locationAbout]]"></i></label>
         <div class="form-control" ><input type="text" ng-model="e.location" id="location"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="api" class="cushion">
          <a href="https://code.google.com/apis/console/" target="_blank">API Key</a>
          <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-content="[[e.APIAbout]]"></i></label>
          <div class="form-control"><input type="text" ng-model="e.API" id="api" placeholder="API Key"></div>
         </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="zoom">Zoom</label>
          <div class="form-control"><input type="range" name="input" ng-model="e.zoom" min="[[e.minZoom]]" max="[[e.maxZoom]]" id="zoom"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="scale">Scale (2x) <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-content="[[e.scaleAbout]]"></i>
          </label>
          <div class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="scale" ng-true-value="2" ng-false-value="1" id="scale" ng-init="scale='false'"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="width" class="cushion">Ancho <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-content="[[e.sizeAbout]]"></i></label>
          <div class="form-control"><input type="number" ng-model="e.width" min="0" max="[[e.maxSize]]" id="width"></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="height" class="cushion">Alto <i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-content="[[e.sizeAbout]]"></i>
          </label>
          <div class="form-control"><input type="number" ng-model="e.height" min="0" max="[[e.maxSize]]" id="height"></div>
         </div>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset ng-show="false">
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="showMarker">Map Marker</label>
          <div class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="showMarker" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" id="showMarker"></div>
         </div>
         <ng-switch on="showMarker">
         <ng-switch ng-switch-when="true">
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="markerColor"> Marker Color</label>
          <div class="form-control"><select ng-model="e.markerColor"
           ng-options="color for color in colors" id="markerColor">
          </select></div>
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <label for="markerSize"> Marker Size</label>
          <div class="form-control"><select ng-model="e.markerSize"
           ng-options="markerSize.value as markerSize.text for markerSize in markerSizes" id="markerSize">
          </select></div>
         </div>
        </ng-switch>
       </ng-switch>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="mapType"> Tipo de Mapa</label>
        <div class="form-control"><select ng-model="e.mapType"
         ng-options="mapType for mapType in mapTypes" id="mapType">
        </select></div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="format"> Formato imagen</label>
        <div class="form-control"><select ng-model="e.format"
         ng-options="format for format in formats" id="format">
        </select></div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <label for="visual"> Efecto Virtual</label>
        <div class="form-control"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="visual" ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false" ng-init="visual='true'" id="visual"></div>
       </div>
      </fieldset>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>
  <div class="col-right col">
   <div class="static">

    <img ng-src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=[[e.location.split(' ').join('+')]]&zoom=[[e.zoom]]&scale=[[scale]]&size=[[e.width]]x[[e.height]]&maptype=[[e.mapType]]&sensor=false[[ e.API !== '' && '&key='+e.API || '' ]]&format=[[e.format]]&visual_refresh=[[visual]][[ showMarker == 'true' && '&markers=size:'+e.markerSize+'%7Ccolor:'+e.markerColor+'%7C'+e.location.split(' ').join('+') || '' ]]" alt="Google Map of [[$route.current.params]]" class="static-map" id="map">

   </div>
   <div class="tabs">


   </div>

  </div>
 </div>

</body>

<script src='http://codepen.io/assets/libs/fullpage/jquery.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.15/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-route-segment/1.3.3/angular-route-segment.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

<script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to :
- register the ngRoute module with your application, if it is not already done
- pass the $routeParams service to your controller

```
var controller = function($scope, $routeParams) { ...
```

Assuming your url looks something like `http://myurl/?LAT=xxx&LNG=yyy`, the $rootParams will be an object with the same values :

```
$rootParams = {LAT:xxx, LNG:yyy}
```

that you can access in your controller with e.g.  `$rootParams['LAT']` and reinject in your view.

$rootParams (succinct) doc from Angular API : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams

Comment: `var myApp = angular.module('myApp',  ['ngRoute'], function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});

var controller = function($scope, $routeParams) {`

Comment: This is the part i already add The ngRoute and in my controller add the $routeParams i need to do shomething else so i can use the $routeParams in my view ?

Comment: Just populate a variable that you can access from your view ? $scope.loc = $routeParams ; depending on the way you handle changes to the URL you might also want to take a look at the $location and/or $route services to monitor changes.

Comment: var controller = function($scope, $routeParams) {
  $scope.route = $routeParams;

Comment: Im using this code, and in my view try to invoke but it gives me just [[route]] , sorry really getting started with angular and is kind of hard to me to get Directives Modules :/

Comment: Can you update your code then ? The only instance of route I can see is a direct call to $route.current.params when you shoud be doing something like '{{route.LAT}}, {{route.LNG}}' (supposing your variable is $scope.route, as you wrote above). If it gives you 'route' instead of an object, it is probably because you forgot the {{ }} necessary to evaluate the variable in your view.

Comment: Its Already Working but in my url index.html?lat=12323 if i print {{route}} just retrun {} an empry array

Comment: That's my bad : you are using $interpolateProvider (why by the way ?) to replace {{}} with [[]], so stick with [[]] to evaluate a controller variable in your view. However, since route is an object, you should probably acess specifically [[route.lat]] and [[route.lng]] if you want to display these url values.

Comment: Its actually a demo i get from CodePen, they change those interpolateProviders, i alredy being using [[]] so dont worry but as a matter of fact if i print [[route]] it gives me an empty {} maybe implement bad the ngRoute ? cause i donwload and keep it locally

Comment: do you directly access your url/?lat=xxx or is your initial url devoid of any lat/lng and gets updated afterwards ? If the latter, you might need some mechanism to update the $scope.route value.

Comment: its initially my default url index.html?var=value

Comment: Could you provide a link to an editable version (jsfiddle or such) ? If you do, I will do some additional tests.

Comment: Perfect sorry for answer until now get without internet http://jsfiddle.net/zw9rqp6j/